# How to convert replacement characters into UTF-8 characters with Python after grabbing text using Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, decoding, string-decoding

I grabbed text from a specific classes child nodes using this subroutine

```
elements = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "gamesRow")))
for a in elements:
    self.formatBets(a.text)
```

and the converted string after applying the `.text` attribute looks something like this:

```
May 05 1
NASHVILLE PREDATORS
-1�+150
o5�+110
-185
More +
4:08 PM
  2 COLUMBUS BLUE JACKETS
+1�-170
u5�-130
+165
```

How would I go about converting those replacement characters (�), as they appear in the original HTML.

In the original HTML, the replacement characters are denoted as fractions, specifically `1/2`

Sorry if this is a bit confusing, I'm new to webscraping and HTML so if this needs more clarification please let me know and I'll edit the question!

Comment: maybe you should check in HTML what encoding it uses and convert it with this encoding. Some pages may still uses different encoding then `utf-8`

Answer (score 0):

Try this change on your code, just encode the text. Are you using python2 or python3?

```
self.formatBets(a.text.encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: I'm using Python3. I'll try this out though! Thank you.